# Get unique number from a column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]Hello,

I want to get the unique number by using a SQL query from the column ProecssInstanceName. The snapshot is attached below.

Right now I am using this query to fetch the below result. The query is

```
select c.StreamName AS Category,ProcessInstanceAppianID as jobId,a.ProcessInstanceName,a.ProcessInstanceTargetDate AS TargetDate,a.ProcessInstanceDescription as TaskDescription,b.Name as department
from InternalUseOnly..ProcessInstance a 
join InternalUseOnly..Departments b on b.KeyDepartment=a.KeyDepartmentEntered AND b.updoperation <2
join InternalUseOnly..ProcessStream c on c.KeyProcessStream=a.KeyProcessStream and c.updoperation <2
where ProcessInstanceCompleted is null
and a.KeyProcessStream in 
(330) and a.updoperation <2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to use `DISTINCT` , but I'm unsure I get the question.

Comment: Post desired output based on the result set you showed in the picture

Comment: Try this... dint test... SELECT SUBSTRING(ProecssInstanceName, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', ProecssInstanceName, len(ProecssInstanceName))) AS number FROM table_name;

Comment: Please provide me with the whole query where shall I add this line in my query. So that I can use this directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?

```
select c.StreamName AS Category,ProcessInstanceAppianID as jobId,a.ProcessInstanceName,a.ProcessInstanceTargetDate AS TargetDate,a.ProcessInstanceDescription as TaskDescription,b.Name as department,
SUBSTRING(ProcessInstanceName,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',ProcessInstanceName),0),7) as code
from InternalUseOnly..ProcessInstance a 
join InternalUseOnly..Departments b on b.KeyDepartment=a.KeyDepartmentEntered AND b.updoperation <2
join InternalUseOnly..ProcessStream c on c.KeyProcessStream=a.KeyProcessStream and c.updoperation <2
where ProcessInstanceCompleted is null
and a.KeyProcessStream in 
(330) and a.updoperation <2
```

EDIT:
I made this:

```
SUBSTRING(ProcessInstanceName, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', ProcessInstanceName), (LEN(ProcessInstanceName) - (PatIndex('%[0-9]%', ProcessInstanceName) - 1) - (PatIndex('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(ProcessInstanceName)) - 1)) + 1)
```

But i think it is madness, better is to parse number in C# or what you use.

Comment: I count 7 digits in those numbers

Comment: @Anoop I miss coma before substring

Comment: In few the lenght of the number is 6 so I am unable to fetch that rest the output is perfect

Comment: As you can see in the 5th column of ProecssInstanceName there is unique code of length 6 I am unable to get that so can you help me to fetch that also in the code column

Comment: I acheived all the code using the query
as department,
SUBSTRING(ProcessInstanceName,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',ProcessInstanceName),0),7)
But at the if there are 5 characters then I am getting N after the code so is there any way to refine it ?

Comment: SUBSTRING has last parameter length, in this case there is 7

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx). `REPLACE` "Webwatcher re-filter URL for " with blank and use `LEFT` together with `PATINDEX` to get the ID and cast is as number.